# This binary was built with the incorrect architecture to run on this machine

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN9P8.png)

Please i need help in solving this.

I enter "flutter doctor" in my terminal and expected to check if cocoapods has installed but show the result in image above.

Comment: Did you try the command and install Rosetta using the sudo as pictured in your example?

Comment: yes I did but return "Installing Rosetta 2 on this system is not supported."

Comment: Am using 2017 macBook air, is there a device compatibility to install Rosetta.

Comment: From the official Apple page, Rosetta has been made available from late 2020 on some models, only with Apple silicon chipsets.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I had to delete my android studio application, which was downloaded with these link, android-studio-2022.1.1.21-mac_arm.dmg .
and dowloaded this instead android-studio-2022.1.1.21-mac.dmg.
probably someone can explain what the arm between (mac --- dmg) means.

Comment: and everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Mac with Ventura 13.1 and Intel Core i5. I had the same issue and resolved it by following this step:

1. Reinstalled "cocoapods" using brew. Link: [enter link description here](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/cocoapods)

2. Reinstalled the Android Studio
3. Reinstalled the X Code command line tools

For me, reinstalling the Android Studio alone didn't work, but the combination above worked.